# How do I process API return without writing to file in Python?

Tags: python, json, api, truncate, in-memory

I am trying to slice the results of an API response to process just the first n values in Python without writing to a file first.

Specifically I want to do analysis on the "front page" from HN, which is just the first 30 items. However the API (https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty) gives you the first 500 results.

Right now I'm pulling top stories and writing to a file, then importing the file and truncating the string:

```
import json
import requests

#request JSON data from HN API
topstories = requests.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')

#write return to .txt file named topstories.txt 
with open('topstories.txt','w') as fd:
    fd.write(topstories.text)

#truncate the text file to top 30 stories
f = open('topstories.txt','r+')
f.truncate(270)
f.close
```

This is inelegant and inefficient. I will have to do this again to extract each 8 digit object ID.

How do I process this API return data as much as possible in memory without writing to file?

Suggestion:

User jordanm suggested the code replacement:

```
fd.write(json.dumps(topstories.json()[:30]))
```

However that would just move the needle on when I would need to write/read versus doing anything else I want with it.

Comment: `fd.write(json.dumps(topstories.json()[:10]))`

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly (though replaced with :30)!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `io` library

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Basically:

```
import io

f = io.StringIO(topstories.text)
f.truncate(270)
```